# Do flat and 2D arrays use the same amount of memory?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

While writing C-code for an answer to a question about a limited-memory situation, I wondered whether any memory space can be saved by using a flat array instead of a (rectangular) two-dimensional array (of which the size is known at compile-time).

So, does e.g. `char a[200][100]` use more memory space than `char a[20000]`?

*(I know it does in some languages, but this is specifically about C)*

Comment: It would occupie same amount of memory as 1-D array  only difference would be how they are accessed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between a[200][100] and a[20000].   For the a[200][100] C uses the number of columns to compute the offset as a is just a pointer to memory of type char.  So if you wanted a[20][5] then C would compute a[20][5] = *(a + 20 * 100 + 5);  I should mention that C is row major (or uses row first in computations).

So if you know the dimensions of your array, you could do the same computation with a[20000].

From a software communications standpoint, if it was static, I would use the char a[200][100] as it communications your structure is 200 rows by 100 columns. This lets the compiler do the computations for you.

Answer (score 3):

> So, does e.g. `char a[200][100]` use more memory space than char `a[20000]`?

No, `char a[200][100]` uses the same amount of memory as `char a[20000]`.

Both need contiguous memory that can hold `20000` `char`s.